# change a script to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, android, database, google-maps-android-api-2

I got script to [calculate distance between 2 coordinates](http://www.kuliahit.com/kuliahit/al/17/Menghitung-Jarak-Koordinat), here :

```
(function() {
        window.onload = function() {
            var map;

            //Parameter Google maps
            var options = {
              zoom: 10, //level zoom
              //posisi tengah peta
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.695001, 113.996544),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            // Buat peta di menu MAP
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('peta'), options);
                var locations = [
                <?php while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($a_peta, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
                ['<?php echo $rs['nama'] ?>', <?php echo $rs['latitude'] ?>, <?php echo $rs['longitude'] ?>],
                <?php } ?>
            ];

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var marker, i;
             /* kode untuk menampilkan banyak marker */
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map,
                    fmap: fmap,
                    icon: 'pics/ico.jpg'
                });

                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    map: map,
                    radius: 10000,    
                    fillColor: '#AA0000'
                });
                circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
                /* menambahkan event clik untuk menampikan
                 infowindows dengan isi sesuai dengan
                marker yang di klik */

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                      infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
            }
        };
    })();
```

you can see that the code is a mix between php & javascript. I want to move it into a full-javascipt file, and didnt know how to do it.

here's the script about '$a_peta' :

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $db = mysql_select_db($dbname);
    if($db){
        $sql="select id, nama, latitude, longitude from jarak order by id";
        $a_peta = mysql_query($sql);
    }
    else {
        print "Database NOT Found ";
        mysql_close($conn);
    }
?>
```

Comment: `window.onload`? Are you not using any JS library?

Comment: This is a nasty situation you got here. In my opinion, the only way to resolve this is rewrite the JS so it uses an AJAX call to get the coordinates.

Comment: Why dont you use a xml file to load all the locations? So you can use the php query in the xml file and load it in your javascript.

Comment: @Hikmah Az you can create a json file containing info about long,lat and name and parse it to get your desired result with separating php and js

Comment: here's some JS libraries that included in my apps :

jQuery Mobile v1.0a3
jQuery JavaScript Library v1.5
jQuery Mobile v1.0a3

it works fine for execute a map, but I need to show more than 1 map in my index.html. I build an android apps using jquery mobile & want to show map in each menu in my navbar.

Comment: Your script is acessing some MySql Database, that's something you can't do using javascript. You should consider using AJAX to request the data trough php, or if you want a offline application think abouth converting to sqlite and sql.js https://github.com/kripken/sql.js

Comment: is it not possible to make it a full javascript file?

Comment: I need it to be online, cause I need to show google maps in my apps

Answer (score 0):

Try using an Ajax call you can see an exemple here : 
http://www.caveofprogramming.com/php/php-json-an-example-javascript-json-client-with-php-server/